# Define user command with argument for Vim

Tags: vim

I am trying to create a user defined command in vim as a replacement for a quickfixlist command

I defined the command like this:

```
:command G -nargs=1 cr <args>
```

Now, when I type  :G 1, I expected vim to execute :cr 1 and go to error number 1 from quickfix list. Instead I get a "trailing characters" error. Any idea what might be causing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Your definition creates `G` as an alias for `:-nargs=1 cr <args>`, taking no arguments. That's why `:G 1` gives you `E488: Trailing characters`.

Running just `:G` results in `E492: Not an editor command: -nargs=1 cr`.

The fix is to move the command attributes before the command name:

```
:command -nargs=1 G cr <args>
```

This way `-nargs=1` is interpreted as an attribute, not part of the command replacement.